# Bootstrap positioning of glyphicon

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image: Dashboard tab]

how can I align the plus sign glphyicon?

HTML CODE :

```
<li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tag"></span>&nbsp Dashboard<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus pull-right"></span></a></li>
```

the first span is to add the tag before the text dashboard

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by first adding a class to the hyperlink tags where this occure:

```
<li>
    <a href="#" class="right-icon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tag"></span>&nbsp Dashboard
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus pull-right"></span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Then using css and the class selector `right-icon` you can do something like:

```
.right-icon > .glyphicon:last-child {
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    right: 2px;
}
```

What I do is take the last child `glyphicon` from the hyperlink and position it absolute on the top right with 2px;